# How do I find the silent install parameters for SceneBuilder?

Tags: scenebuilder, chocolatey

I want to create a [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package to install [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/), so I'm looking for a way to install Scene Builder silently in command line.

I downloaded a installer (SceneBuilder-8.4.1.exe) and try to install like below.

```
> SceneBuilder-8.4.1.exe /silent
```

However, it launches a install dialog similarly in the case when I double click a installer.

Does Scene Builder installer has a capability to install silently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to find out what kind of installer is used and look up the silent installation flags or you can try experimentally. The Chocolatey documentation says something like this

[image: choco-help]

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package#silentargs-string

If you pass a "help" parameter to the installer it indicates some silent switches and some documentation.

```
PS> ./SceneBuilder-9.0.1.exe /?
```

```
---------------------------
Setup
---------------------------
The Setup program accepts optional command line parameters.



/HELP, /?

Shows this information.

/SP-

Disables the This will install... Do you wish to continue? prompt at the beginning of Setup.

/SILENT, /VERYSILENT

Instructs Setup to be silent or very silent.

/SUPPRESSMSGBOXES

Instructs Setup to suppress message boxes.

/LOG

Causes Setup to create a log file in the user's TEMP directory.

/LOG="filename"

Same as /LOG, except it allows you to specify a fixed path/filename to use for the log file.

/NOCANCEL

Prevents the user from cancelling during the installation process.

/NORESTART

Prevents Setup from restarting the system following a successful installation, or after a Preparing to Install failure that requests a restart.

/RESTARTEXITCODE=exit code

Specifies a custom exit code that Setup is to return when the system needs to be restarted.

/CLOSEAPPLICATIONS

Instructs Setup to close applications using files that need to be updated.

/NOCLOSEAPPLICATIONS

Prevents Setup from closing applications using files that need to be updated.

/RESTARTAPPLICATIONS

Instructs Setup to restart applications.

/NORESTARTAPPLICATIONS

Prevents Setup from restarting applications.

/LOADINF="filename"

Instructs Setup to load the settings from the specified file after having checked the command line.

/SAVEINF="filename"

Instructs Setup to save installation settings to the specified file.

/LANG=language

Specifies the internal name of the language to use.

/DIR="x:\dirname"

Overrides the default directory name.

/GROUP="folder name"

Overrides the default folder name.

/NOICONS

Instructs Setup to initially check the Don't create a Start Menu folder check box.

/TYPE=type name

Overrides the default setup type.

/COMPONENTS="comma separated list of component names"

Overrides the default component settings.

/TASKS="comma separated list of task names"

Specifies a list of tasks that should be initially selected.

/MERGETASKS="comma separated list of task names"

Like the /TASKS parameter, except the specified tasks will be merged with the set of tasks that would have otherwise been selected by default.

/PASSWORD=password

Specifies the password to use.



For more detailed information, please visit http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

The [Universal Silent Switch Finder](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ussf) says this is an Inno Setup installer and suggests some switches.

[image: ussf]

Comment: Perfect answer!
I didn't notice that `SceneBuilder-9.0.1.exe` has `/?` parameter.
`/?` parameter doesn't work with `SceneBuilder-8.4.1.exe`.

Comment: It's possible they switched installer technology between 8 and 9. The ussf app is fairly useful. I'd give that a try.